# How to retrieve data from a table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table that stores all billing history for each user. I need to display certain fields from this table in an invoice for the user. When I call the variables in my view I get a 'undefined method error'.
Here is a small example of what i have in the view.

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Invoice Number
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= @billing_history.id %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Issue Date
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= @billing_history.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y' ) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tax Number</td>
    <td>
      ######
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is my controller

```
def invoice
  @company = current_user.company
  @billing_history = BillingHistory.find_by(id: params[:billing_id])
  # raise 'not for you' if @billing_history.company != @company.id
  render pdf: 'billings/invoice'
end
```

Here is my full error message

```
> `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
4:     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
5:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,                  initial-scale=1.0" />
6:     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
7:     <title>Invoice <%= @billing_history.id %></title>
8:     <style>
```

`

Comment: You really want to use `.find(params[:billing_id])` instead of `.find_by(id: ...)`. The former will raise a `ActiveRecord::NotFoundException` if the record is not found which will cause rails to bail and return a 404 response instead of blowing up with a nil error.

Comment: If you follow @max's suggestion, and it still doesn't work, can you edit your question to include the output of `rake routes` or `rails routes` depending on your version of rails?

Comment: Also, I will request you to have a guard conditions before rendering. Just to watch out on these kinds of issues.

Answer (score -2):

try using **byebug** place it after

`@billing_history = BillingHistory.find_by(id: params[:billing_id])` **this line**

then check what is the value of @billing_history if it's `nil` then use `The Safe Navigation Operator (&.)` like @billing_history&.id ,that won't raise any error.

Comment: This is a comment. Not an answer. Using the safe nagivation operator here is a pretty bad suggestion as it will just suppress the error.

Comment: yeah did you not see 'try using byebug' he can debug can know what's causing the error.